# String substring methods

Tags: java, string

I'm reading data from a txt file and my goal is to display certain elements from that file. 
I use 'contains' method to choose correct line to display, then I use substring method to display fragment of that line. In this method I have to indicate the beginning and the end of my substring. It means that I must know how many letters from my line I have to cut out to show the proper data.
Is there any method which would display substring which begins with certain character/word?

For example, for string line like "Finders, keepers Losers, weepers"
to display "keepers Losers" I write java code:

`if myFile.contains("Finders"){(System.out.println(line.substring(10, line.length()-10));}`

I'd like to find method or idea how to display the same fragment where parameters might be for example: first few letters and/or last few letters of substring. Instruction which would work like that: "display substring of given string which starts with "kee" and ends with "Losers"

Comment: Err, `String.indexOf()`? The connection with `BufferedReader` is zero.

Comment: regular expressions would work.